# How use particular word from class in css?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i have some `'<a> <i> <label>'` in my page like below with the class

```
<a class="icon-home"></a>
<label class="icon-pencil"></label>
<i class="icon-display"></i>
```

i need to create css with `margin-right:10px`  when class start with `"icon-"`

some thing like below:

```
<style>
.icon-* {margin-right:10px}
</style>
```

Comment: I would add another class and use that if I were doing this.  Example: `class="icons icon-home">` then `.icons {margin-right:10px}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: @Zenith I know, but what if he has two classes?

Comment: I didn't notice the space before the second one - good job :)

Comment: What is better for performance - doing a selector like this or adding an extra class called icon to all the objects and then using `.icon {}`?

Comment: @Pete `[class^="icon-"]` is faster. I made a test and the result was 43ms against 70ms. But you have to remember: `[class^=*]` is a CSS 3 selector — no chance for IE 8 without hacks.

Comment: Using an ordinary class is faster than an attribute selector.  However, if you have 50+ icon-* classes (think FontAwesome), the attribute selector will give you significantly slimmer CSS.

Comment: @cimmanon I agreed with you until I did the test. Maybe I have done something wrong, but I have tested three times.

Comment: @chiefGui: Just because something is part of CSS3 does not automatically make it unsupported in IE8 (it claims to be CSS2.1 compliant, which it is, but that does not mean it supports absolutely no CSS3). CSS3 attribute selectors are supported in IE8... *and* IE7.

Answer (score 0):

**you can use like this**

`[class*="icon-"]{
   margin-right:10px;
}`

The star designates that the proceeding value must appear somewhere in the class value. That way, this covers icon-

`[class^="icon-"]{
   margin-right:10px;
}`

This is a cinch with the carat symbol. It’s most commonly used in regular expressions to designate the beginning of a string. If we want to target all tags that have a `class` which begins with  `icon-`, we could use a selector similar to the snippet shown above.

Comment: I don't see where "col" has anything to do with this question - can you elaborate please?

Comment: it's a class name you can modify it according to you

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the dash-match syntax:

```
[class|="icon"]{ margin-right:10px; }
```

This will correctly match:

```
<a class="icon-home"></a>
<label class="icon-pencil"></label>
<i class="icon-display"></i>
```

...with the **added benefit** of also matching something like:

```
<a class="icon"></a>  /* No hyphen required */
```

...while still keeping out this:

```
<a class="icons"></a> 
/* Won't match this. "icon" can *only* be followed by a dash */
```

This approach has some limitations too:

- won't select if there's a white-space after "icon"
- icon *must* be at the beginning of the class attribute string (like with `^=`)

Tests here: http://jsfiddle.net/mhfaust/Bh95t/